# Is border="0" the same as leaving it blank?

Tags: html, html-table

Is

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
```

The same as

```
<table align="center">
```

?

Comment: It is probably different for each browser.

Comment: What happens when you try it in each browser?  Do you see the same result?

Comment: Don't touch those attributes. It isn't 1998 any more. Use CSS instead.

Comment: @MikeMooney When I try it in Firefox it moves slightly nothing major tho. The same happens in Chrome. Im using the upto date versions of both

Comment: @Quentin Im a 1st year CompSci student didn't have much choice on what I could use

Comment: @Alex — You're being taught techniques that have been out of date for over a decade? Oh dear.

Comment: @Quentin Gotta start somewhere

Comment: @Alex — Yes, and that place is structured, semantic markup followed by stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border will be the same but unless you add the cell padding and cell spacing as zero you'll get around 2px of each on your cells.

You could set this to zero in your style sheet though and leave them black. But the default behavior will add the padding/spacing in.

Answer (score 1):

As far as HTML only is considered, border="0" is the same as not using the border attribute at all. (Note that border=“0” with “curly” quotes, as in the heading of the question, is invalid in HTML; the quotes, if used, must be "straight" or 'single-straight'.) But in the presence of CSS, it may make a difference; the explicit attribute border="0" may override CSS settings.

Regarding cellspacing and cellpadding, mentioned in the body of the question, they do make a difference. Their default values, by implementations (the specs are silent about this), are small positive integers, typically 2.